# Else if Loops how to stop the user typing anything but true or false?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

So i have added a catch i cant see any errors with this now but when i run the program it repeats Incorrect input please try again! Incorrect input please try again! Incorrect input please try again! until i turn the program off. Any ideas where ive gone wrong?

```
do {
  try {
    boolean updown = sc.nextBoolean();
    if (updown == true) {
      grid[x + 1][y] = 'S';
      grid[x + 2][y] = 'S';
      grid[x + 3][y] = 'S';
      grid[x + 4][y] = 'S';
      drawGrid(grid);
    } else if (updown == false) {
      grid[x][y + 1] = 'S';
      grid[x][y + 2] = 'S';
      grid[x][y + 3] = 'S';
      grid[x][y + 4] = 'S';
      drawGrid(grid);
      retry = 2;
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Incorrect input please try again!");
  }
} while (retry == 1);
```

Comment: How can `updown` (a boolean) be anything except `true` or `false` ? I'm confused...

Comment: Your strategy is flawed.  `true` and `false` are the *only* `boolean` values.  `Scanner.nextBoolean()` cannot return anything else.  On the other hand, you're in luck: that method will throw an `InputMismatchException` if it cannot convert the next token to `boolean`, so all you have to do is catch that.

Comment: Badly formatted code.

Comment: @John Bollinger Hi thanks for your reply, what should i search up on a tutorial for this? i have tried inputmissmatch before as i thought this was the solution before i posted however the videos were all very out of context for what i am doing.

Comment: @Synch He is a beginner and i'm sure everyone starts doing like this and later it improves, no need for rude comments , atleast he tries. :)

Comment: Hi people I have edited the code hopefully its nicer now, i dont know what you mean by badly formatted i think it looks clean, i managed to get a catch working but it doesnt re loop the whole frid

Comment: @Chop take a look at how the code is now formatted: increase the indent every time you open a `{`; decrease indent when you close a `}`. This helps you (and others) to see the start and end of loops/conditionals/try-catches, which helps you to understand the code's flow more easily. I did this with [google-java-format](https://github.com/google/google-java-format), but any IDE worth using will also do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `boolean` only has two possible states, it can **only** be `true` or `false`; there is no third state. You can also combine multiple assignments, you only need an `else` and `drawGrid` can be *common*. And if you're concerned about invalid input, you can `catch InputMismatchException` or check if the `Scanner` has a `boolean`. Or both. Like,

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
try {
    while (!sc.hasNextBoolean()) {
        if (!sc.hasNextLine()) {
            System.err.println("no input");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.err.println("Not a boolean, try again: " + sc.nextLine());
    }
    boolean updown = sc.nextBoolean();
    if (updown) {
        grid[x + 1][y] = grid[x + 2][y] = grid[x + 3][y] = grid[x + 4][y] = 'S';
    } else {
        grid[x][y + 1] = grid[x][y + 2] = grid[x][y + 3] = grid[x][y + 4] = 'S';
    }
    drawGrid(grid);
} catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
    System.err.println("Expected true or false.");
    System.err.println(ime.getMessage());
    ime.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are many troubles as well but you can do this:

```
}
        else if (!sc.hasNextBoolean()) {    (user needs to get error message 
                System.out.println("Error , input is not boolean value");
                return;
}
            if (updown == true) {
            grid[x+1][y] = 'S';
            grid[x+2][y] = 'S';
            grid[x+3][y] = 'S';
            grid[x+4][y] = 'S';
            drawGrid(grid);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a way to determine whether the user input is a valid boolean value.

#### How to determine if user input is a boolean

The `Scanner` class has a built-in method for that: `Scanner#hasNextBoolean()`. In your sample code, simply call

```
sc.hasNextBoolean();
```

If it returns `true`, the user input is a valid boolean (`true` or `false`). If it returns `false`, the user input is something else.